# Is it possible to filter the params for a request to a Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

If I set up param validation on a Grape API request is it possible to get a hash of just the validated params?

```
desc "My Grape API request handler"
params do
  requires :name
  optional :description
end
post do
   puts params.inspect # has all the params passed to request, 
                       # even params not defined in validation block
end
```

Is there another way to just get the `params` limited to the ones listed in the param validation block? Kind of like how Rails strong_parameters works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using rails...

You can create a strong param helper in the base class of your api so your mounted endpoints can also have this helper:

```
module StrongParamHelpers
  def strong_params
    ActionController::Parameters.new(params)
  end
end
```

Include this in the base class of your api:

```
helpers StrongParamHelpers
```

Then in each api endpoint class, you create another helper method kind of similar to how rails does it:

```
helpers do
  def user_params
    strong_params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email) # etc...
  end
end
```

Then just call `user_params` in your routes:

```
desc "My Grape API request handler"
params do
  requires :user do
    optional :username
    optional :email
    # etc
  end
end
post do
   User.create user_params
end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

It might be late but for anybody passing by, you can use `declared_params`.
https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#declared

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to start with Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query

For example:

```
params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
```